# php - Selecting a query base on the session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a table `users` that has `user_id`,`user_firstname` And also table `borrow` that has `borrow_book`,`user_id` that is foreign key to the table `users`.
 What I want to do is to query the table `borrow` But only display the sessioned user. Here is my code so far.

```
<?php 
    $sel_admin =
"select b.book_title, borrow.borrow_date,u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, borrow.borrow_remain
from borrow
inner join book b 
on borrow.book_id= b.book_id
inner join users u 
on borrow.user_id=u.user_id";
    $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
    ?>
```

EDIT: I edited my code

```
    <?php 
                    session_start();
 $sel_admin =
 "select b.book_title, borrow.borrow_date,u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname,
borrow.borrow_remain
from borrow
inner join book b 
on borrow.book_id= b.book_id
inner join users u 
on borrow.user_id=u.user_id WHERE borrow.user_id ="?><?php " $_SESSION ['user_id']"; ?>
```

but it still gives me Array to String notice.

Comment: what do you get when you `print_R($_SESSION['user_id']`?

Comment: It is just a formatting error, sir. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the user_id stored in the $_SESSION variable, you could add

```
WHERE borrow.user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

Unless I am missing something?

```
<?php 
    $sel_admin =
"select b.book_title, borrow.borrow_date,u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, borrow.borrow_remain
from borrow
inner join book b 
on borrow.book_id= b.book_id
inner join users u 
on borrow.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE borrow.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
    ?>
```

This assumes you are storing user_id in the $_SESSION variable

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. I edited my question. can you help me out?

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I'm sorry im not used to using the `.`